# How can I get any row which substring is any?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a varchar(max). I would like to know if it's possible to get all rows that contains any substring from a list of it.

I know that for one value I can use like 'AAA%', but I don't know if like has any way to say something like where IN().

Something like this:

```
select * from TableA where
TableA.Field1 contains any (select Fild1 from TableB where field2 > 5);
```

Where TableA.Field 1 and TableB.Field1 are varchar(max).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server includes the CONTAINS function so something like this will work fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON CONTAINS(TableA.Field1, TableB.Fild1) AND TableB.field2 > 5
```

You may need to adjust for your requirements.

Here is the documentation on contains
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: This will return duplicated TableA rows if one TableA.Field1 has several TableB.Fild1:s matches.

Comment: @jarlh - if that is an issue then a simple DISTINCT will solve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from TableA
where exists (select 1 from TableB
              where TableA.Field1 like '%' + TableB.Fild1 + '%'
                and TableB.field2 > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @query varchar(max)

select @query = 'select * from t1 where ' + 
          STUFF
          (
             (
                select ' OR col1 like ''' + col1 + '%''' 
                from t2 
                for xml path('')
              ),
          1,4,'');

execute(@query);
```

## Example

**Table - t1**

```
+----+-------+
| id |  col1 |
+----+-------+
| 1  | AAAAA |
| 2  | BBBBB |
| 3  | CCCCC |
| 4  | DDDDD |
| 5  | EEEEE |
+----+-------+
```

**Table - t2**

```
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
| AA   |
| BB   |
| CC   |
+------+
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+
| id | col1  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | AAAAA |
| 2  | BBBBB |
| 3  | CCCCC |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: you are going to make a where clause with an or for each row?  What if t2 contains 5000 rows?